# std::fstream - slow second read

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, g++, fstream

I'am having troubles with fstream while reading large binary files(2 GigaBytes). Using this test code I create fstream and then read until EOF. Then clear flags and reset position to the beginning of the file. Then I read it again.  Problem is, that the second read(second while cycle) is always significantly slower.

I need to get this solved for Embarcadero RAD Studio XE7. Same beheaviour of slower second read can be replicated in MS Visual 2010. First read is done in HDD maximum speed (about 140 MB/s), second is always done at quarter of it (35 MB/s).

Oddly, when I use g++ 4.9.2 on my Debian, both first and second readings are done with the same time as I would expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

char buffer[400000];
int main()
{
    std::fstream stream;
    std::string filename = "largeFile.bin";
    stream.open(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

    while(stream.good()){
        stream.read(buffer, 400000);
    }

    printf("first read complete");

    stream.clear();
    stream.seekg(std::ios::beg);

    while(stream.good()){
        stream.read(buffer, 400000);
    }

    printf("second read complete");
    stream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I omitted time measure of both while cycles, since it is not significant for this problem.

Am I doing something wrong when reading multiple times from start to EOF, on once opened file?

Comment: A long long time ago it was important to set the read buffer size to something like 64KB due to some hardware caching mechanisms involved... But I don't have any clue if this is still valid. Not sure how it explains the degradation of your performance though.

Comment: I tried to set the buffer to various sizes (and now even to the 64KB), but sadly there is no difference.